# Script Handler for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to study using Python in Google App Engine and can't get the tutorial to work. But ultimately, I would want to write a Python script that would return list of files in a folder in server to JavaScript.

Here's what I currently have:

```
+MainProj  
   + static  
      +scripts  
          . __init__.py  
          . helloworld.py  
   . app.yaml
```

In helloworld.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

In app.yaml

```
application: applicationname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: static.scripts.helloworld.app
```

I am getting a server error

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

Anyone can help what's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every folder in your package path ('static.scripts.helloworld.app') needs to have `__init__.py` in it to import properly, so either add one to 'static' or (more sensibly, in my opinion) move helloworld.py up to the top, and use 'helloworld.app' in your app.yaml.

Comment: this solved it. thanks! Just added __init__.py in 'static' folder

Answer (score -1):

All you need in your `app.yaml` handler is:

```
 - url: /.*
   script: static.scripts.helloworld.py
```

And make sure you also have in your `helloworld.py` at the bottom code to actually start the application and listener:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
# granted, you might want to replace "webapp" with "webapp2" here

def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I added the code you mentioned and changed app.yaml and now I get a different error. Fatal error when loading application configuration:
threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: static.scripts.helloworld.py

Comment: I get the server error same as before. I am just following google app engine tutorial from [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld)

Comment: If you turned threadsafe off, you shouldn't be receiving a threadsafe error.  Are you sure you re-uploaded the app?  Try `threadsafe: false`

Comment: I did not get the threadsafe error. I was talking about the HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error). I tried false and it's not working also. I am just accessing the server through http://localhost:8080 and have started the application through Google App Engine Launcher.

Comment: Well in that case, why don't you use the Google App Engine launcher to check the logs?  That would show you pretty neatly where the exception is.

Comment: Your solution would work for CGI, python runtime. John is running python27 - WSGI env. They are different things. Plus, CGI is kinda old and less efficient.